# Use headsepline without reducing the text body height

Tags: koma-script

In a document that uses the class `scrreprt` and the page style `headings`, how can a horizontal line under the header be introduced with class option `headsepline=true` without decreasing the text body height?

Consider the following image comparing `headsepline=true` and `headsepline=false`

[image]

As mentioned in the KOMA script documentation, the header is considered a part of the text body if `headsepline=true`. However, I would like to preserve the available height for text (due to a tight page limit I have to obey). With other words: how can I move the red line to the green line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline,headinclude=false}
```

The `headsepline` option sets automatically `headinclude=true`. `headinclude=false` changes it back.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline,headinclude=false}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

But it seems to me that there is a bug in version 3.19 because

```
\documentclass[headsepline,headinclude=false]{scrreprt}
```

should do the same and did the same in version 3.18. **Update:** In version 3.20 this will work again, see: [Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in KOMA-Script 3.19a](http://www.komascript.de/release3.19a) (German).